# Async issue on nodejs POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, promise

I am trying to apply a custom function inside a Post Request, but it returns undefined.

I know that this is some kind of async issue, I just cant figure out what might be the problem.

Chunk of code where problem resides

```
console.log(text); // <---- This shows correct value
A.prepare(function (text) { 
    console.log(text) // <---- This shows undefined
    B.write(text, function (response) {
        sendTextMessage(sender,response.message)
        return response.message;
    });
});
```

Whole code

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
    // addPersistentMenu();
    let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        let event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
        let sender = event.sender.id;
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            let text = event.message.text;
            console.log(text);
            A.prepare(function (text) {
                B.write(text, function (response) {
                    sendTextMessage(sender,response.message)
                    return response.message;
                });
            });   
        }
        if (event.postback) {
            let text = JSON.stringify(event.postback);
            sendTextMessage(sender, "Postback received: "+text.substring(0, 200));
            continue;
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Comment: Because that is a callback function. You are just giving the first parameter the name text. And not passing the value of text to the function.

Comment: which vaue you want o pass in `test` of this` B.write(text, function (response) {`?

Comment: @abdulbarik I want to pass event.message.text

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue, not an async one.

In the line

```
A.prepare(function (text) {
```

`text` is actually the parameter passed to the function and used internally to the function itself. It does not refer to text you are logging in the line above.

Comment: Any idea how to solve it ? I tried wrapping it on an outer function, didnt work either.

Comment: Just remove/rename `text` argument from `A.prepare` callback

Comment: I would remove A.prepare if I didn't need it but I need the function to be there.

Answer (score 1):

### *Update*

> You are getting `text` value as `undefined` since you are accessing it in a `callback function`.
>   And you have also given `text` parameter in the `callback function`. And `Priority always goes to local` that means every time you'll get the local value of `text` which is
>   `undefined` now.
>   you must change one of those variable names.

As I have changed `text` to `text1` now you can get `text1` value in `callback function`

> And if you want to pass variable in `A.prepare()` function, you can add multiple parameters on basis of requirement.

like this:

```
A.prepare(param1,param2,param3,...,function(text){
    //Do your stuff
})
```

Here is you updated code:

```
app.post('/webhook/', function(req, res) {
    //  addPersistentMenu();
    let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        let event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
        let sender = event.sender.id;
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            let text1 = event.message.text;
            console.log(text1);
            A.prepare(function(text) {
                B.write(text1, function(response) {
                    sendTextMessage(sender, response.message)
                    return response.message;
                });
            });


        }
        if (event.postback) {
            let text = JSON.stringify(event.postback);
            sendTextMessage(sender, "Postback received: " + text.substring(0, 200));
            continue;
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Comment: I would also like to pass the variable to A .. Also what's difference from my code and yours ?

Comment: Answers that only contain code and no explanation of what you changed or what the problem can always be made better by including some explanation.  Further, they make it quite difficult for quick readers that just drop by to get anything useful from your answer without detailed comparison of your code vs. the original code.  Please add explanation.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your suggestion, yes will do always. A well explained answer will help to all needy users

Comment: So, I thought you were going add an explanation to this answer (you can use the "edit" link to modify your answer).